# Admobs sometimes appear twice on different locations

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, admob, iad

We are adding `admobs` as a backup ad-system for countries without `iAd`. But sometimes the ads appear twice, the second ad sometimes in the middle of the screen about 100-200 px above the other ad. It seems like the second ad only appears when visiting a view that already has an ad.  It kinda feels like the ad-call is in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`, but we don't. Or `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` gets called on outside `viewDidLoad`-call for ad. Anyone know anything about this?

**EDIT:**
They CAN appear both at once, without having to revisit a view that already has an ad.

**EDIT(code)**
basically:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [self createAdBannerView];
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView];
}

-(void) createAdBannerView
{
    bannerView = [[AdBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CGRect bannerFrame = bannerView.frame;
    bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    bannerView.delegate = self;
    bannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifiersPortrait,AdBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape,nil];
}

-(void)bannerView:(AdBannerView*)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self.bannerView removeFromSuperview];
    GbannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height-99, 320,50)];
    self.GbannerView.adUnitID=@"xxxxxxx";
    self.GbannerView.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.GbannerView];
    [self.GbannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```

Also, if someone knows: In views containing tableViews, the locations of the admobs is wrong. It gets stuck behind a tabbar, even though the location takes this into account. This does not happen in a normal UIView. whatz..

Comment: Could you provide code to fix the problem :)

Comment: @iProgrammed I have added the basic code running the show.. nevermind typos, I had to write this by hand here.

Comment: Check out my new Answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you pull out the tableView question into its own question. There's an example of how to do this [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/?repo=adcatalog-ios#git/AdCatalog/Classes/AdvancedLayoutUseCases/TableViewExample), but I don't know if that satisfies your specific case).

Is there a reason you're not just using [AdMob mediation](http://mediation.admob.com/) here? They've got support for iAd and setting it up with client code is pretty easy.

For your specific case, I wonder if `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError`: is getting continuously called even after you remove `AdBannerView` from its superview. Why don't you create one `GADBannerView` and `AdBannerView` at the start in `viewDidLoad`:, then check if it exists before instantiating any new ones?